# Very slow update performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am parsing a CSV file, for each row I want to check if corresponding entry exists in the database, and if it does I want to update it, if it doesn't I want to enter a new entry.

It is very slow - only around 30 entries per second.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Using node, mongodb, monk

```
 function loadShopsCSV(ShopsName) {
    var filename = 'test.csv'

        csv
            .fromPath(filename)
            .on("data", function(data) {               
                           var entry = {
                                PeriodEST: Date.parse(data[0]),
                                TextDate: textDateM,
                                ShopId: parseInt(data[1]),
                                ShopName: data[2],
                                State: data[3],
                                AreaUS: parseInt(data[4]),
                                AreaUSX: AreaUSArray[stateArray.indexOf(data[3])],
                                ProductClass: data[5],
                                Type: data[6],
                                SumNetVolume: parseInt(data[7]),                                
                                Weekday: weekdayNum,                              
                                WeightedAvgPrice: parseFloat(data[8]),

                            }


                            db.get(ShopsDBname).update(
                                {"PeriodEST" : entry.PeriodEST,
                                 "ShopName": entry.ShopName,
                                 "State" : entry.State,
                                 "AreaUS" : entry.AreaUS,
                                 "ProductClass" : entry.ProductClass,
                                 "Type" : entry.Type},
                                  {$set : entry},
                                  function(err, result) {

                                  }
                            );
                    }
                }
            })
            .on("end", function() {
                console.log('finished loading: '+ShopsName)
            });
    }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest to localize problem:

- replace `.on("data", function(data)` with dummy `.on("data", function() {return;})` and confirm speed of csv parsing.
- turn on [mongo profiler](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) `db.setProfilingLevel(1)` and check slow log if there is any query slower than 100 ms.

If there are no problems above - the bottleneck is in one of nodejs libraries you are using to prepare and send query.

Assuming the problem is with slow mongodb queries, you can use [explain](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) for the update query for details. It may be the case it does not use any indexes and run a table scan for every update.

Finally, it is recommended to use [bulk](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/) operations, which was designed for exactly your usecase.

Comment: all my update queries take more than 100ms - I can see it in the mongo console. I couldn't find any example where you update element by element via the bulk way...

Comment: Unfortunately monk does not support bulk API yet: https://github.com/Automattic/monk/issues/85

Comment: Quick search returns an example for sails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019267/how-to-properly-do-a-bulk-upsert-update-in-mongodb

Comment: If changing library is not an option, you need to analyse your database performance. The first step is to update question with result of `db.YourCollection.explain().update(....typical update query...)`

Comment: I have no idea what it does, or what it means, but after adding an index on the fields I query by doing `db.shops.createIndex(("PeriodEST":1 .. ` it sped up dramatically

Comment: Apparently there were no indexes, so every update did full table scan. With correct indexes it picks matching documents from the index.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating with no write concern? as MongoDB blocks until whole update is successful and DB sends back that acknowledgement? Are you on cluster or something? (might want to write into primary node if so)

after your  {$set : entry},
{writeConcern: {w: 0}}

Comment: I think monk driver only takes two arguments, in this case, `users.update({}, {}, fn);` so I have nowhere to pass the writeconcern argument. It's ignored if I add an extra argument before fn.