# MongDB bulk write UpdateOne w/upsert option inserts new documents (c# driver)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection that requires frequent updating. The structure is as follows:

```
{
  ObjectId _Id;
  string EntryKey;
  string Description;
  string SearchTerm;
}
```

There is a unique index on the `EntryKey` field. I am creating upsert operations like so:

```
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(e => e.EntryKey, model.EntryKey);
var update = updateBuilder.Combine(
  updateBuilder.SetOnInsert(e => e._Id, ObjectId.GenerateNewId()),
  updateBuilder.SetOnInsert(e => e.EntryKey, model.EntryKey.ToLower()),
  updateBuilder.Set(e => e.Description, model.Description),
  updateBuilder.Set(e => e.SearchTerm, model.SearchTerm));

var op = new UpdateOneModel<SearchEntry>(filter, update){ IsUpsert = true, Hint = "EntryKey_1" };
bulkList.Add(op);
```

Using the exact same input data for each test with a fresh mongo instance, the first iteration succeeds and the second one fails with `E10000: duplicate key error collection` on the EntryKey field

When I remove the unique constraint from the index, duplicated documents are created in the collection (with the exception of `_Id`)

When I run the command in the shell using the same failed ID, the command succeeds and the document is updated.

```
db.search.bulkWrite([
  {
    updateOne: {
      "filter": { "EntryKey": "ad544f72-496f-4eee-bf53-ffdda57de824" },
      "update": {
        $setOnInsert: {
          _id: ObjectId(),
          "EntryKey": "ad544f72-496f-4eee-bf53-ffdda57de824"
        },
        $set: {
          "Description": "This is a description",
          "SearchTerm",: "search"
        }
      },
      "upsert": true
    }
  }
]);
```

I expect the documents that match the filter predicate to get updated instead of either throwing a duplicate key error (when the unique index is enforced) or insert essentially duplicate documents.

I see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019267/how-to-properly-do-a-bulk-upsert-update-in-mongodb) question the accepted answer is to separate updates from inserts. If that's the case, then what's the point of upsert if it cannot be used in the manner being tried here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the code runs the first time, it will create a document where `EntryKey` is set to `model.EntryKey.ToLower()`.

In the second run, `EntryKey` is compared with `model.EntryKey`.  Since it was downcased in the upsert, this will only match if there are no uppercase letters in `model.EntryKey`.

If there are any, the filter will fail to match, and it will attempt to upsert, but fail after converting to lowercase.

To make that consistent, also downcase in the filter, like

```
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(e => e.EntryKey, model.EntryKey.ToLower());
```

Comment: thank you. It's the little things...